# web3 py - peers

Tags: web3.py

I am trying to get the number of peers that my node is connected to.

I am connected to INFURA endpoint:

```
from web3 import Web3
w3 = Web3(
    Web3.HTTPProvider(("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3....."))
)

print(w3.geth.admin.peers()) // Gives error
```

I receive following error:

**ValueError: {'code': -32601, 'message': 'The method admin_peers does not exist/is not available'}**

Am I doing something wrong?

I made sure I am connected by:

```
>>> w3.isConnected()
True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following line should solve your issue:

```
print(w3.net.peerCount)
```